# Saving .gitignored files

Tags: github, gitignore

I created a new branch in my git repo and I'd like to not have to copy and paste in all of my gitignored files every time I switch branches. is there a way to save a file to the repo but just not have it show on github or is this just one of those things?

Comment: If you really need the content in those files, you may need to think of a different way to store that content, like in environment variables, or have a script that can generate the content during your build process.

Comment: @MForMarlon it's actually the environment variables that this is happening to. I added my `.env` to my `.gitignore` but when I created a new branch there was no .env. Worse yet, they `.env` I created in the new branch doesn't persist.

Comment: What OS are you on? As the answerer said, the files should remain on your local system no matter what you do

Comment: @MForMarlon it worked after I ran `git rm --cached <file>`, idk why I had to do that but hey, it's working so I'm happy. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since git is ignoring those files, they'll stay around as you switch branches.

Comment: but they don't I created a new branch and the files weren't there so I created them within this new branch and once I switched back to the main and then switched to the new branch again they weren't there.

Comment: How are you switching branches?  The default behaviour of `git checkout` should leave them alone.

Comment: yea I initialized the branch with `git checkout -b <new branch>` and the `.env` file wasn't in the new branch

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I had to do this but I just ran:

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

for each file I needed hidden, rewrote them in `.gitignore`, and it worked how it was supposed to after that.